# Git status after changing branches

Tags: git, branch

Recently I did some work in a branch called "dev" and needed to embark on some new initiatives, so I created and changed to branch "dev-crud" after making sure everything was up to date in "dev" before leaving - i.e., git status showed that I was up to date with no items listed.  After doing some work in "dev-crud" and not having committed anything, I switched back to "dev" and was surprised to see that it was aware of my work in "dev-crud", i.e.:

```
$ git checkout dev
M   MDSCommitteeWS.iml
M   pom.xml
M   src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
A   src/main/webapp/edu/mayo/crud/Committee.java
A   src/main/webapp/edu/mayo/crud/CommitteeCrud.java
A   src/main/webapp/edu/mayo/crud/UtilityCrud.java
M   src/main/webapp/edu/mayo/dbconnection/WSAction.java

Switched to branch 'dev'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.
```

So after making changes in "dev" are these files also going to be added when I decide to add all my changes in "dev?"  Should I have committed my changes in "dev-crud" before switching back to "dev?"  At this point in time my intent is for them to be two separate lines of development.  Thanks!

Comment: You should have commited the changes before changing branches.

Comment: Changes in your index or worktree stay there until you commit them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will be added and committed if you just run `git add . && git commit` in `dev`.

Though it's okay to `git add` and `git commit` before switching to `dev` so that these changes won't be applied to `dev`, `git stash` in `dev-crub` is better. It leaves the work tree clean and the changes are stored. When you'd like these changes back after going back to `dev-crub`, run `git stash apply`(the last stash is kept) or `git stash pop`(the last stash is dropped) to restore the changes.

Git also allows you to checkout two or more branches into individual folders, so you don't have to switch back and forth in the same directory. With the help of `git worktree`, you can save a lot.

```
git worktree add <some-other-path> dev
```

Now `some-other-path` has been created if it did not exist and the code of `dev` is checked out there. You can run git commands in `some-other-path` to manipulate `dev`. `git worktree` is a relatively new feature, so Git of old versions doesn't support it.